# Radio Button selections are not stored Android

Tags: android, radio-button, switch-statement, android-alertdialog

I created an Alert Dialog Box with Radio buttons, when ever i select the radio button track-lists, it dose not remember the tracks during next the selection so i cant able to know which track is currently playing. `int currentselection = -1;`
Please check the code and tell me if the there is any problem with my code. Thanks in Advance..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b1;
int currentselection = -1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Track #1", "Track #2","Track #3" };

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Track");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }); 
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, currentselection,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface mdialog, int item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (item) {
                    case 0:
                        currentselection = 0;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        currentselection = 1;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        currentselection = 2;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    mdialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not remember"?

Comment: @Dany Joumaa It dose not shows the previously selected item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

you need to either store it to the database, storage or use a static variable and change the value of the variable anytime user changes the radiobox.

Cheers,

Comment: Can you explain me about static variable ??

Comment: For just storing small values, database should not be used as per android guidelines. Shared preference is the best and easiest way to do it..

Comment: @SaiKiran You can follow Sushil method, actually, it will works well and looks quite consistent for android dev. About the static val as I said, you can declare it to a separated class. I do not remember exactly but it is something like public static String MY_VAL = "";

Answer (score 0):

```
Radio button does not preserve value. So you loose them after exiting. You can handle radio button scenario in combination with sharedpreferences.

After setting radio button add it to shared preferences like:

 private RadioButton mWifiDataButton = null;
 private RadioButton mWifiButton = null;

in onCreate() .. 

 mWifiDataButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_wifi_data);
 mWifiDataButton.setOnClickListener(this);

 mWifiButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_wifi_only);
 mWifiButton.setOnClickListener(this);



Editor ed = pref.edit();
ed.putBoolean("pref_radio_wifidata",mWifiDataButton.isChecked());
ed.putBoolean("pref_radio_wifi",mWifiButton.isChecked());

and next time retrieve the values like this:

mWifiDataButton.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("pref_radio_wifidata", true));
mWifiButton.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("pref_radio_wifi", false));



Then in onClick() handle it properly:

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        switch(v.getId()){


            case R.id.radio_wifi_data:
                pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                boolean wifidataState = pref.getBoolean("pref_radio_wifidata", true);
                mWifiDataButton.setChecked(!wifidataState);
                mWifiButton.setChecked(wifidataState);
                Editor ed = pref.edit();
                ed.putBoolean("pref_radio_wifidata", !wifidataState);
                ed.putBoolean("pref_radio_wifi", wifidataState);
                ed.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.radio_wifi_only:
                pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                boolean wifiState = pref.getBoolean("pref_radio_wifi", false);
                mWifiButton.setChecked(!wifiState);
                mWifiDataButton.setChecked(wifiState);
                Editor ed1 = pref.edit();
                ed1.putBoolean("pref_radio_wifi", !wifiState);
                ed1.putBoolean("pref_radio_wifidata", wifiState);
                ed1.commit();
                break;

ed.commit();
```

Comment: Hi Sai.. in case any answer solves your purpose, please accept the answer so that others can benefit by reaching to correct answer easily. thanks